# Feature Vector Partitioning

Tags: image, algorithm, opencv, search, tree

I'm reading about image search and I've gotten to the point where I have a basic understanding of feature vectors and have a very basic (definitely incomplete) understanding of rotation invariant and scale invariant features. How you can look at multi-sampled images for scale invariance and corners for rotational invariance.

To search a billion images though there is no way you could do a linear search. Most of my reading seems to imply a K-d tree is used as a partitioning data structure to improve the lookup times.

What metric is the K-d tree split on? If you use descriptors like SIFT,SURF, or ORB there is no guarantee your similar keypoints line up in the feature vectors so I'm confused how you determine 'left' or 'right' since with features like this you need the split to be based on similarity. My guess is in euclidean distance from a 'standard' then you do a robust nearest neighbor search, but would like some input on how the inital query into the KD tree is handled before the nearest neighbor search. I would think a KD tree needs to be comparing similar features in each dimension, but I don't see how that happens with many key points.

I can find a lot of papers on the nearest neighbor search, but most seem to assume you know how this is handled so I'm missing something here.

Comment: I've never worked much in CBIR so I don't have much to add, but one method for matching scale and rotation invariant features is to take a distinct feature and calculate the angles that the other features are at in relation to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. All that feature descriptors present image as a point in multidimensional space. Just for the sake of simplicity, let's assume that your descriptor dimension is 2. Than all your images would be mapped onto two dimesional plane. Then, kd-tree will split this plane into rectangular areas. Any images that fall within same area would be considered as similar.

That means, btw, two images that lie really close to each other, but in different areas (leafs of the kd-tree) will not be considered as similar.
To overcome this issue, cosine similarity can be used instead of  euclidian distance. You can read more about the subject in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).

Comment: I'm aware of how to do this with basic descriptors like most common color, most prominent hue, standard deviation of a parameter, etc.. I don't see how you do this with SIFT, SURF, or ORB features when there is no guarantee you will hit them in the order it is expecting in 2 different images if one is oriented differently. How is an orb feature left or right from another? I don't understand how you encode them into the kdtree.

Comment: For each key point you have a (say) 128 dimensional descriptor. You descriptor is always built in the same order, and thus it is promised that you will compared apples to apples. Then you need to match all the key points of your image to the database, and find images that most of their key point descriptors are close to those of your image.

Comment: I suggest you read the original [David Lowe's paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf) and more practical [OpenCV tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html)

Comment: The kd-tree is not used to split the 128-dimensional descriptor. It splits the 128 space into hypercubes, and all the points in the same hypercube are considered neighbors of your key descriptor. For simple example, let's go back to 2-d descriptors. Let's say you have a kd-tree defines 4 areas - the 4 quadrants. Then if you get one descriptor [1, 5] it's neighbors will be all the data points in first quadrant, and for second descriptor [ -5, -12.7] - all the  point that lie in third quadrant

Comment: Ah i see you could definitely key on an individual keypoint descriptor. So if you queried multiple keypoints in a kd-tree then prune the nearest neighbor search for images that are in common. Granulating the problem.